Why is threejs lighting fun such as pointlight and ambientlight not working with version "three": "^0.164.1"
I was doing my very first threejs small project with vite and threejs library
I added these light function in js file,
// emit light evenly in all directions from specific point in space
const pointLight = new Three.PointLight( 0xff0000, 1, 100 );
pointLight.position.set(5, 5, 5);



// to spread the lighting across the entire scene
const ambientLight = new Three.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
scene.add(pointLight, ambientLight);

Inside of package.json,
{
  "name": "three-demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
    
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "three": "^0.128.0"
  }
}

The problem is that the lighting function works perfectly with three dependencies "three": "^0.128.0" but when changes to latest version "three": "^0.164.1" and run npm install, then the lighting function not working
Edit: In saying of not working, it is like
with the latest version, with set of 100 intensity
with the older version, with set of 100 intensity
What it should be like

And "not working" means? Does it throw an error? If yes, what error? Does it not show the expected result? IIf yes, what do you expect, what do you get?

If I had to shoot, it would probably be about the intensity of the lights, which has changed since r155.
I assume that by not working you mean that the light/objects are invisible.
Try set
const pointLight = new Three.PointLight( 0xff0000, 100, 100 );
pointLight.position.set(5, 5, 5);

In general, however, it would be good if you provided more details, as derpirscher suggested.
Also take a look at this thread:
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/updates-to-lighting-in-three-js-r155/53733

Yeah i have tried setting intensity with the latest version and not working so i posted it on stackoverflow, sorry for the lack of details in the question
